# Where is Response.json() in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular8

I use to do this in Angular 4/5:

```ts
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http"

public listTemplates(): Observable<EmailTemplate[]> {
    let url = `${this.apiUrl}/templates`
    this.http.get(url).map(
        response => this.parseTemplates(response.body)),
        error => new ErrorObservable(error)
    )
}
```

Now, with Angular 8, I'm trying to use the `HttpClient` class:

```ts
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http"
import { Observable } from "rxjs"
import { ErrorObservable } from "rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable";

public listTemplates(): Observable<EmailTemplate[]> {
    let url = `${this.apiUrl}/templates`
    return this.http.get(url)
        .pipe( // ??
        map(  //??
            response => this.parseTemplates(response.body)),  // ?? HttpResponse
            error => new ErrorObservable(error)
        )
    )
}
```

1. `map` does not exist anymore
2. `pipe`, how to use it?
3. `HttpResponse` does not have a `json` method anymore

I think I should be able to use `.get` to obtain an `any` object that will be my JSON object (as `.get` documentation says), but how?

How can I use `pipe` or `map` (or both) to manage JSON object returned by the `.get` with a custom parsing and return a collection or an Observable of a collection?

**[Solution]**

```ts
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http"
import { Observable } from "rxjs"
import { ErrorObservable } from "rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable"
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

    public listTemplates(): Observable<EmailTemplate[]> {
        let url = `${this.apiUrl}/templates`   

        return this.http.get(url).pipe(
            map(
                data => this.parseTemplates(data),
                error => new ErrorObservable(error)
            )
        )
    }
```

I still do not know how to get the HttpResponse for the cases where I need to check the HTTP status or some HTTP header. I understand that what `get` is returning is driven by the type returned by the function (because of the `pipe` call).
I tried to use `get<HttpResponse<any>>` but didn't worked.

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/guide/http? You could have been using `HttpClient` from Angular 4.3. Also it's worth checking e.g. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration for the transition to RxJS 6 (which came with Angular 6 IIRC).

Comment: I readed it and also many examples online; always shows get() returning ```MyObject[]``` or ```Observable<MyObject[]>```. The problem is I need to parse the MyObject with a custom parsing, the client model is different from the server model and I want to put some logic also, so I was thinking to use ```any``` but still cannot figure out a full working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example similar to your use case. I get an array of JSON objects and convert/parse them to an array of my data interface (GeneratorOffer):

```
getGeneratorOffers(): Observable<GeneratorOffer[]> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>('shop/offers').pipe(
    map(
      jsonArray =>
        jsonArray.map(jsonOffer => {
          try {
            return buildGeneratorOffer(jsonOffer);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Offer could not be parsed: ${error}, json: ${JSON.stringify(jsonOffer)}`);
          }
        }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error('Offers could not be loaded', err);
        return of([]);
      })
    )
  );
}
```

The actual parsing for each JSON object happens in `buildGeneratorOffer()`.

Answer (score 1):

`pipe` groups operators from rxjs. Any operator returns an observable.
In order to use `map` you need to import it.

`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 0):

So , there is no response.json in Angular 9 i guess as i searched a lot for it.
But instead we can directly convert the response object to the desired type and use it, like in the example below using response object as an array to fetch the data in my array.

```
   export class PostsComponent{
    posts : any[];
      constructor(http : HttpClient){
          http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                  .subscribe((response:any[]) => {
                      this.posts=response;
                  });
      }
    }
```

Comment: HI @Animesht, welcome and thanks for the response. Yes, in some situations the _subscribe_ is still a working solution and as you pointed out the _any_ type can be used (also _Object_ probably).
In my case the code shows a Provider, so I need to return an Obesrvable<..>, with the ``pipe( map(), catchError())`` syntax you have an Observable<..> response while with _subscribe_ I'm not able to obtain that (not directly at least).  Thanks for your reply anyway.